# Modal easyAdmin 4

Tags: php, translate, easyadmin, symfony6

I'm reaching out to you as I've been searching for several hours to change the default language of EasyAdmin 4 with Symfony 6. I've tried quite a few solutions, but none of them have worked (or I might have used them incorrectly). If you have any advice or tips, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance for your responses.

I tried to modify the modal templates to change the text. I also modified the default_language in the framework.yaml file.

Comment: Did you set the ea_LanguageName Convar?